# How to generate dynamic imageviews by using a string array

Tags: android, imageview, arrays

I want to set bitmaps to two imageviews generated from multiple image urls and have to set ontouchlistener/onclicklistener for last imageview to change the bitmap images dynamically.Can anyone give me some suggestion to do this?

Here i'm using im0(imageview) only,but i want to load images dynamically to im0,im1 and im2(imageviews) respectively.And have to set onclicklistener to last imageview itself.

My MainActivity is:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    arraylist=new ArrayList<String>();
    im0=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    im1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    im2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    jsonobj = JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.195/Madhu/anrdmulti/multidocretrieve.php");

    try 
    {
        jsonarr = jsonobj.getJSONArray("uploadimages");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) 
        {
        JSONObject  jsonobj1 = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
             id=jsonobj1.getInt("id");
             JSONObject jsobj=jsonobj1.getJSONObject("allimages");
            for(int j=0;j<jsobj.length();j++)
            {
                JSONArray image_array=jsobj.getJSONArray("images");
                for(int k=0;k<image_array.length();k++)
                  {
                    String image= image_array.getString(k);
                    arraylist.add(image);
                  }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    allimagesarr=arraylist.toArray(new String[arraylist.size()]);               

        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            Drawable s=LoadImageFromWebOperations(allimagesarr[j]);
            im0.setImageDrawable(s);
        }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

My xml file is:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: Can you please post code without how god even help you ?

Comment: means add dynamically imageView or just replace the images in imageview.

Comment: @Dilavar
I'm using three imageviews in that only i have to set images dynamically.Check my activity and xml codes.

Comment: you should perform JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL, LoadImageFromWebOperations in async task